# Processing large number of text files in java

Tags: java, file, file-io, ftp, parallel-processing

I am working on an application which has to read and process ~29K files (~500GB) everyday. The files will be in zipped format and available on a ftp.

**What I have done:** I plan to download and the files from ftp, unzip it and process using multi-threading, which has reduced the processing time significantly (when number of active threads are fixed to a smaller number). I've written some code and tested it for ~3.5K files(~32GB). Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32247100/3737258

However, the estimated processing time, for ~29K files, still seems to be very high.

**What I am looking for:** Any suggestion/solution which could help me bring the processing time of ~29K files, ~500GB, to 3-4 hours.

Please note that, each files have to be read line by line and each line has to be written to a new file with some modification(some information removed and some new information be added).

Answer (score 2):

You should **profile** your application and see where the current bottleneck is, and fix that. Proceed until you are at your desired speed or cannot optimize further.

For example:

- Maybe you unzip to disk. This is slow, to do it in memory.
- Maybe there is a load of garbage collection. See if you can re-use stuff
- Maybe the network is the bottleneck.. etc.

You can, for example, use [visualvm](https://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide you one solution for your issue, since it might be that you simply reached the hardware limit.

Some Ideas:

- You can parallelize the process which is necessary to process the read information. There you could provide multiple read lines to one thread (out of a pool), which processes these sequentially
- Use `java.nio` instead of `java.io` see: [Java NIO FileChannel versus FileOutputstream performance / usefulness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605332/java-nio-filechannel-versus-fileoutputstream-performance-usefulness)
- Use a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools#Java)
- Instead of the profiler, simply write log messages and measure the
  duration in multiple parts of your application
- Optimize the Hardware (use SSD drives, expiriment with block size, filesystem, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in parallel computing then please try Apache spark it is meant to do exactly what you are looking for.